# Unable to open new tab in browser?

Tags: javascript, html

This may sound like duplicate question but i don't know what problem i am facing.

This is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
function open()
{
var win = window.open('http://stackoverflow.com/', '_blank');
if(win){

win.focus();
}else{
alert('Please allow popups for this site');
}
}
</script>
<div align="center">
<h4>Online Users</h4>
<ul>
<li onClick="open()">John</li>
</ul>
</div>
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans Condensed:300italic,300,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <div class="nomessages">

        <img src="../img/unnamed.jpg" id="noMessagesImage" />

        </div>
<div class="chatscreen">

        <ul class="chats">
            <!-- The chat messages will go here -->
        </ul>

    </div>

 <form id="chatform">

        <textarea id="message" placeholder="Write something.." rows="10" cols="30"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="SEND"/>

    </form> 


<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="../js/chat.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I  expect to open a new tab when i click John but instead it is opening the url on same window.I don't know what am I doing wrong here

Comment: I'm not so sure but I think this behaviour is browser-controlled - I mean, when to open new window or new tab.

Comment: I am using firfox 28.0 I am also facing same problem in chrome.So is there any alternative of this

Comment: @laaposto's answer worked for me. But this is because my browser is set to open in a new tab, not a new window. The only way to open something is with `window.open`. But is the browser who decides how it will be opened.

Comment: But it is also not opening a new window even

Comment: @Dontvotemedown So there's nothing i can do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
 <li onClick="window.open('http://stackoverflow.com/', '')">John</li>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8g55U/)

Comment: I want to open a new tab not window

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't choose between new tab or window.

Comment: @Fresher You can do nothing to choose to open in a new tab instead of a new window.

Answer (score 5):

Change the name of function, defining a function without scope is same as defining window.functionName

so when you define open, you are over-riding existing window.open
so change the name of your function to *open2* or something else.

```js
function open2() {
   var win = window.open('http://stackoverflow.com/', '_blank');
   if(win){ 
       win.focus();
   } else {
     alert('Please allow popups for this site');
   }
}
```

and in your HTML

```html
<li onclick="open2()">John</li>
```

Answer (score 3):

use openx() instead of open() .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>


function openx()
{
var win = window.open("http://stackoverflow.com/", "_blank");
}
</script>
<div align="center">
<h4>Online Users</h4>
<ul>
<li onclick="openx()">John</li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mb232/)

Answer (score 3):

Try using different name for the function..

```
<script>
function open1()
{
    var win = window.open('http://stackoverflow.com/', '');
    if(win){

    win.focus();
}
else{
   alert('Please allow popups for this site');
}
}
</script>
```

**HTML Markup**:

```
<li onclick="open1()">John</li>
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, it depends on your browser settings: opening in a new window, or opening as a new tab.
So probably, you can't force browser opening new tab instead of window.

Comment: But is also not opening a new window even

Answer (score 2):

To open win you should:

```
<li onClick="window.open('https://stackoverflow.com/', '_blank')">John</li>
```

If in browser not set special behaviour on prefer new tabs or windows it will open in new tab. But if you`ll add additional params for window it will open in new win.

```
<li onClick="window.open('https://stackoverflow.com/', '_blank','height=200,width=200')">John</li>
```

Besides, this topic have a lot of discussion:
[2011 year StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-using-javascript)

Comment: and also do not try to override standart functions. open === window.open